# App engine ssl not deleting

Tags: ssl, google, google-app-engine

I'm trying to cancel an old, soon to be expiring SSL Certificate and replace it with a new one in the Google Cloud Console for App Engine. Both certs have been assigned to the custom domain name. The old cert is still functioning on the website, even though the console says it's not. I'd like it gone, and replaced with the new one (my-cert-1). This video shows the situation. Any ideas?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XfR6eofwzc

Answer (score 1):

Most of the console issues regarding SSL certificates for custom domains should be resolved at this time. There is still one outstanding issue where deleting a cert will occasionally fail with HTTP error 405.

The progress of this issue is currently being tracked publicly here, feel free to star it for updates:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13287